# set vee-validate field value programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I want to set filed value programmatically in **Vue 3.2.31 - Vee validate 4.5.11**, I update modelValue but the field value is not updating its own.

My vue template:

```
<div>
<label :for="get_id">
  {{ input.label }}
  <span class="text-danger" v-if="is_required">
    *
  </span>
</label>
<div class="input-group" :class="{'p-loading p-loading--left p-loading--bgWhite': input.loading}">
  <Field
    :name="input.name"
    :rules="input.rules"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    v-slot="{field, value}"
  >
    <input
      :value="field.value"
      @blur="field.onBlur"
      @input="field.onInput"
      @change="field.onChange"

      v-bind="input.attrs"
      class="form-control"
      :id="get_id"
      :name="input.name"
    >
  </Field>
  <span class="input-group-append" v-if="!empty(input.inputPrefix)">
    <span class="input-group-text">{{ input.inputPrefix }}</span>
  </span>
</div>
<p class="t-12 text-muted mt-1" v-if="input.helpText">{{ input.helpText }}</p>
<ErrorMessage class="d-block text-danger ml-1 mt-1" :name="input.name" />
```

My vue scripts:

```
import get_id from "../../assets/js/functions/id";
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import empty from "../../assets/js/functions/empty";

export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  components: {
    Field,
    ErrorMessage
  },
  props: {
    input: {
      required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number]
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    normalizedInput() {
      return Object.assign({
          rules: "",
          attrs: {}
        }, this.input
      );
    },
    get_id() {
      return this.input.id ?? get_id(true);
    },
    is_required() {
      return this.normalizedInput.rules.includes("required");
    }
  },
  methods: {
    empty
  },
  created() {
    this.input.attrs = Object.assign(this.normalizedInput.attrs, this.$attrs);
  }
};
```

Everything is good, until I change the modelValue in parent component,
the modelValue in input component changes correctly,
but the field value does not update, neither does the input value.

What's wrong with my code?
is there any way to achieve this?

any suggestion for code enhancement appreciated

Comment: Please add your code as text using the `code formatting`, instead of an image.